# Skype4py: Error: Skype attach timeout Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, skype4py

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. 
I have a script which connects to a bookmarked chat and writes out a message.
I am maintaining a cronjob to execute this after every half an hour. In 12.04 it worked fine.

```
*/30 11-19 * * 1-5  DISPLAY=:0;export DISPLAY;/path/script.py >> /path/errorStatus.log
```

The script correctly on executing through the terminal, but it is giving "Attach timeout" error  on executing through the cron-job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISPLAY=:0;export DISPLAY;PID=$(pgrep gnome-session);dbus=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-);export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$dbus;/path/script.py >> /path/errorStatus.log

The cron job was not working as the env was not set correctly...

Firstly I tried running the script in cron environment :: -

[How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with)

I compared the user-env and cron-env and found that exporting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS works for the script.

[Shell script with export command and notify-send via crontab not working. Exported variable is set by a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415117/shell-script-with-export-command-and-notify-send-via-crontab-not-working-export)